# all itemreader from each job are initliazed at startup

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have 2 jobs each one with 2 steps (each one with reader, processor, writer).
All is working well but when i launch job N°1 (command line with --spring.batch.job.names=job1Name), all the IteamReader are called (ItemReader from job N°1 and job N°2)
Log look like this :

```
start reader 1
start reader 2
start reader 3
start reader 4
```

From this Code (very simplified) for job 1 :

```
@Configuration
public class Job1Class
{
  ...

   @Bean
   public @NonNull Job job1(){
      return jobBuilder.get("job1Name")
      .start(step1())
      .next(step2())
      .build();
   }

   @Bean
   public @NonNull Step step1()
   {
     return stepBuilder.get("step1")
     .<MyClass, MyClass>chunk(1024)
     .reader(reader1())
     .processor(processor1())
     .writer(writer1())
     .build();
   }

   @Bean
   public @NonNull Step step2()
   {
     return stepBuilder.get("step2")
     .<MyClass, MyClass>chunk(1024)
     .reader(reader2())
     .processor(processor2())
     .writer(writer2())
     .build();
   }

   @Bean
   public @NonNull ItemReader<MyClass> reader1()
   {
      log.debug("start reader 1");
    //code
   }


   @Bean
   public @NonNull ItemReader<MyClass> reader2()
   {
      log.debug("start reader 2");
    //code
   }

   ...
}
```

and the same for job2 :

```
@Configuration
public class Job2Class
{
   ...

   @Bean
   public @NonNull Job job2(){
      return jobBuilder.get("job2Name")
      .start(step3())
      .next(step4())
      .build();
   }

   @Bean
   public @NonNull Step step3()
   {
     return stepBuilder.get("step3")
     .<MyClass, MyClass>chunk(1024)
     .reader(reader3())
     .processor(processor3())
     .writer(writer3())
     .build();
   }

   @Bean
   public @NonNull Step step4()
   {
     return stepBuilder.get("step4")
     .<MyClass, MyClass>chunk(1024)
     .reader(reader4())
     .processor(processor4())
     .writer(writer4())
     .build();
   }

   @Bean
   public @NonNull ItemReader<MyClass> reader3()
   {
      log.debug("start reader 3");
    //code
   }


   @Bean
   public @NonNull ItemReader<MyClass> reader4()
   {
      log.debug("start reader 4");
    //code
   }

  ...
}
```

I'm missing something ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you start your Spring Boot application, all beans will be created and added to the application context (ie the bean definition methods will be called), that's why you see the log messages. But that does not mean all readers will be executed, only those of the specific job will be called at runtime.